# how to redirect ONLY dead links to my homepage

Tags: website

How can I write htaccess to do the following:

redirect ALL dead links on www.mysite.com 
to 
www.mysite.com (homepage)

Obviously I only want the dead links redirected.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Just redirect 404 (missing) files to a path you want

ErrorDocument 404 http://www.somesite.gov/

or just go home...

ErrorDocument 404 /

http://www.bignosebird.com/apache/a7.shtml

Comment: See KarmaWhore's note about the difference between the two ways of using ErrorDocument.  Also note that a custom error document that links to an internal search page (perhaps with some pre-filled context-sensitive magic based on the original URL?) is sometimes preferable to a blind redirect to the home page, at least from a user's standpoint :-)

Comment: Good point.  I figured cashbagg could use that as a starting point - showing him you can obviously stay within your own site but even go somewhere else.  A site-map or search page is definitely a better way to go.

Answer (score 4):

remember that ErrorDocument 404 http://www.somesite.gov/ will actually hand the search engines a 302 or temporary redirect and won't remove those pages from the search engines.

ErrorDocument 404 /    is probably more correct as it will generate a 404, but will send the person to the homepage.  Any graphics and links should have absolute relative paths or you should put a <base href="/"> to make sure everything displays properly.

Comment: Good point.  Was mainly trying to show you can stay in your site, or even push them somewhere else.  Although most people would want to keep a user once they have brought them in.  :)

Comment: "absolute relative paths"? Absolute or relative, can't be both.

Answer (score 0):

This should also do it, and pass the failed page as an argument:
`RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?badrequest=$1`
I haven't tested it mind.